# Calling the function name

Tags: function, lua, call

As a beginner in Lua, I am sorry if the answer on this is easy.
I was trying to call a function within a code, yet after 2 hours of searching I couldn't find the wanted results. (Maybe I use the wrong search query's?)

Example code

```
function Test123 ()    
    SayTest = True
    if SayTest = True then
        -- This Is where I want to call the function name Test123, 
        -- yet I can't seem to succeed in this since it is just 
        -- starting a new function
        SystemNotice ( role, function) 
    end
end
```

This should be the result:

```
function Test123 ()    
    SayTest = True
    if SayTest = True then        
        SystemNotice ( role, 'Test123')
    end
end
```

If anyone can help me out, I would be thankful. If I am still being unclear, just tell me and I will try to describe it better. My excuses for my limited English.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Try to describe in simple words what your code should do. The fragment you posted is too limited and, moreover, has a number of syntax problem, as @solarbear already pointed out. What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: @user2884099 Lua uses keywords `true` and `false` for bool literals -- note the case.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati - It seems that OP wants to get the name of the current function in realtime (`'Test123'` in this case).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Mmm ... you mean a sort of C++ "this" for the currently executing function? It could be. Anyway the logic of that flawed code is fairly obscure, IMO.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You got me, this was indeed my intention. Got kinda late when I typed this, and since the lua functions are actually being used for a game I didn't felt like copying the whole function.

Answer (score 2):

In Lua functions are actually *values*. That means they do not really have a name, you can only assign them to a variable or table field, but since the value itself has no concept of its name, you can't retrieve it.

That said, with the `debug` library, you can do this:

```
function getfname()
    return debug.traceback("", 2):match("in function '(.-)'");
end
function bar()
    print(getfname())
end

bar();             -- prints bar
foo = bar;
foo()              -- prints foo
knerf = {rab = bar};
knerf.rab()        -- prints rab
```

Note that this only works with the default Lua error handler or one that returns the same or very similar output, however you can obviously modify the pattern to suit what you need.

**Read this:** I would not advise this solution for performance-intensive tasks. Both string matching and the traceback are not really suited for this. Also, obviously the debug library must be enabled so you can actually use the traceback function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration lacks an`end`.

```
function Test123 ()
end
```

Read the functions chapter from [the Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html). Just for the record, your `if` will also need an `end`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a construct that just goes against the Lua philosophy that functions are first class citizens:
a function is just another value, and as such it has no name.

A variable can be assigned a value, thus binding a function to a name.
But that name can change. or a function can have multiple names. Which one to pick?

A better solution would be creating an anonymous function with an upvalue (a closure) instead:

```
function genTest(name)
    return function()    
        SayTest = true
        if SayTest == true then        
            print ( 'role', name)
        end
    end
end

Test123 = genTest('Test123')
Test123()
foobar = Test123
foobar()
```

This creates a function with a bound local variable name (see [PiL 6.1](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html) ).